# Apache Beam DirectRunner not working with PubSub emulator

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Previously, I had no trouble getting the Beam DirectRunner to work with the PubSub emulator. However, lately it isnt working anymore.

A couple of things that I have set up:

PubSub emulator:

- `gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=test-project --host-port=127.0.0.1:8088`
- `gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init`

When I use snippets from [this](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/) repo, I can make topics and subscriptions just fine in that emulated project.

However, when using the DirectRunner (`runner="DirectRunner"`) in my (Python) Beam pipeline, the runner keeps trying to find the resources in Google Cloud instead of using the local one. Thus it says subscription `x` does not exist. Revoking default credentials makes the pipeline fail and complain about default authentication missing altogether. Setting `--no-auth` in `PipelineOptions` doesnt help either. I have ran the `gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init` command in the terminal that DataFlow is using. Am I missing something?

I tried setting the following options with no luck:

```
"--no_auth", 
"--runner=DirectRunner"
"--pubsubRootUrl=http://127.0.0.1:8088",
"--project=test-project",
"--pubsub_root_url=http://127.0.0.1:8088",
```

I tried revoking the default credentials. I tried unsetting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` . I tried setting `CLOUDSDK_API_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDES_PUBSUB=127.0.0.1:8088`. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Oh God, was missing `$(gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init)`. Works fine now.